# Keep the battery from charging fully (without Lenovo power manager)

Tags: windows-7, battery, thinkpad

Is there any tool (for Windows 7) to set a threshold for when the laptop battery should stop charging? I could use the *Lenovo Power Manager*, however I actually prefer Windows' native power management for the other tasks.

Comment: What is your outer problem?

Comment: I agree with @DavidSchwartz, what is it that you're trying to accomplish, overall?

Comment: The charger control interface is not standardized -- you need to use the manufacturer's tool.

Comment: Also, check this question if you (most likely) have a Li-Ion battery, http://superuser.com/q/5853/147104

Comment: Based on idea in answer linked by @FredrikD I charged the battery to 53% and took it out because this laptop is almost always plugged in. Will check after a week or so if the state of charge has decreased. It's probably best to keep it at about 50%. EDIT: Looks like 40% SoC is best as stated in the answer too: http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_store_batteries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you are trying to keep your battery at a level lower than 100% (let's say 40%). I wanted the same thing in the past because I used my laptop mainly as a desktop, and keeping the battery at 100% all the time was not necessary and not healthy for it. What I found is that even though in theory it is possible to find software controlling the level of the battery while the OS is running, when the computer is powered off/put to sleep, it will start charging because there is no hardware support for such feature - keeping the battery at lower level.

So in conclusion, if you have laptop different from Lenovo/ThinkPad, I think there is no way to achieve this.

Comment: Actually, I do have a Thinkpad. I just can't stand Lenovo's power manager so I'd prefer to use Windows' manager and set the charging thresholds using a different tool.

Comment: Why isn't it healthy for the battery to be charged to 100%?

Comment: Looking for the same and after one hour googling, I came up  to the same conclusion as Simeon. The only setting under windows seven is "balanced". I read and agree with: "According to what I know, laptop battery charge management is implemented by means of proprietary system and can be configured only by using software utilities provided by the laptop manufacturer's.". Which is my case on a (real good) Samsung's laptop for example, but recharging threshold is still adjustable to a single number of 80%, not more, not less.

Comment: This answer is wrong.  The Sony software for my Vaio does this just fine.

Comment: But, the "Sony software" would only be able to control the charging levels for Sony laptops, right? The OP was asking for solutions for Thinkpad laptops. I could only find an [obscure solution for Linux](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Tp_smapi#Battery_charge_control_features "Tp smapi: Battery charge control features") systems, but not for Windows :-\

Answer (score 4):

It is actually possible to set charging thresholds on ThinkPads through a proprietary API once introduced by IBM. Not only does it support a stop threshold (so your battery never exceeds e.g. 75% charge) but also a start threshold. I really like this feature. So if you often switch between your desk and walking through your office building you won't keep your battery charging and discharging between 90 and 100%. Because it's an API kept secret and unique to ThinkPads there are no generic implementations neither in other hardware brands nor different software tools (with `tp_smapi` being the only exception as an reverse-engineered implementation for Linux).

For years I've been using `tp_smapi` under Linux to set these values. According to Thinkwiki and my own tests booting Linux, setting the thresholds and rebooting to Windows works while keeping the set values. I can confirm that a complete battery rundown resets the values. I don't know yet what's happening when the system is shut down because my OS ever set the values again during boot.

I think it's quite awkward to boot two operating systems one after another just to set this option. Unfortunately to my knowledge there's no other way under Windows than using the Lenovo Power Manager. What are crappy program it is.

Maybe you can set the values with the power manager and than disable it? The battery control is done by hardware/firmware and no program is required to be running for the settings to take effect.

I have the battery manager running anyways and just didn't found the setting which brought me here. Hope the information above helps anyone.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for the pointer. `tpacpi-bat` works great for the Haswell X1 Carbon.

Answer (score 3):

i am using Lenovo PM and charge thresholds set were not working as charging would continue till 100% was achieved. I upgraded my BIOS and it solved the problem. now charge thresholds settings are working

Comment: how to update bios?

Comment: Good for you, my BIOS is up to date, and PM still doesn't give a * about the threshold. I  have to physically remove the battery (from an old T400) to avoid full charge.

Answer (score 2):

Install Lenovo Energy Management 7 > reboot your PC > then when windows has loaded <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> > type `msconfig` find the tab `Startup`

Un-check `Lenovo Energy Management software` but keep `Lenovo Battery Management software` Then reboot again

Comment: good job. My laptop is g40 80

Comment: Just work for 2 days.. :(

Answer (score -1):

I did not work for me in the beginning because Z500 didn't know it had a battery.

1. First do a clean install of Windows 7.
2. Install all the drivers only for Lenovo site and respect the restarts. Install Lenovo Energy Management last. Go to Lenovo Energy Management and set it for full Performance.
3. The indicator in the animation should be far right not center.
4. Go to Advanced Power Settings in Control Panel -> Lenovo Energy Management and hit ENABLE
5. Now you restart and you should be able to do the firmware update
6. If you cannot do the firmware update then uninstall LEM, remove ACPI from Device Manager, Reinstall LEM, Enable again.
7. If you cannot do the firmware update then try battery gauge reset in Safe Mode and remove ACPI after, and then Reinstall LEM, Enable.

The video is useful only if your Lenovo Z500 recognizes battery.﻿

Answer (score -2):

A good practice is to unplug the laptop on occasion and let the battery drain down and plug it in when you get the warning. Batteries that are never discharged do not last as long a batteries that have been discharged. Once a battery is fully charged it should only be trickel charged and this does not happen on laptops. Charging a battery that is fully charged will shorten it's lifespan.

Comment: Not true. 1) Laptops do not continue charging the battery once it is fully charged, and 2) a lithium-ion battery should be stored at around 40% state of charge, rather than constantly charge-cycled.  If the laptop allows it, it should be operated with the battery detached instead.

Comment: @DragonLord - Most systems will throttle the CPU if the battery is disconnected.